# Are questions about torture ok?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[A method to cause maximum pain to a human](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/48940/a-method-to-cause-maximum-pain-to-a-human) asks how to cause the most pain to a human while torturing him to death.  The question lays out parameters, including not wanting the person to go out of his mind too quickly, because pain includes being aware enough for it to register.

Frankly, this question squicks me, enough that I haven't read most of the answers in order to be able to process flags.  I *get* that this is for a work of fiction involving a psychotic despot.  I'm not criticizing the person who asked the question in order to be able to write that fiction.  I know that my reaction is just that -- *my* reaction, and that some classes of fiction turn me off is not a reflection on others.

But, all that said... is this the kind of content we want here?  Do we have a minimum level of (reaching for a word) "decorum" or a maximum level of squickiness, beyond the bounds of which we shouldn't host content?  Or does anything go, so long as it's not hate speech, rude, or close-worthy for the reasons that apply to all questions?

Let me anticipate some responses:

- Yes, I'm quite aware that there's lots of information out there that's way more gruesome, explicit, or sadistic than anything we're likely to get here.  This isn't about *preventing access* to such information (which would be impossible); it's about whether we want it *here*.
- This is not a free-speech issue.  First, as already noted, it's not about suppressing information.  Second, a community is allowed to set bounds about what is welcome within its confines, and the owner of a service (SE) is allowed to set rules about what it will host.

A question about this question has been [raised on the SE-wide meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281862/162102).  But the question doesn't violate any SE rules, so the proper place to discuss the propriety of such questions is here on Worldbuilding Meta.  (I brought this up in our chat room to gauge initial reactions, but there aren't a lot of people around on the weekend.)

Comment: Only after asking this did I again encounter [this question](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/3394/28) (which I answered, even).  I'm not sure whether to close this as a dupe or make it more about the prompting question.

Comment: As a mod elsewhere, and a vaguely interested third party, I'd consider this a more generic question. I'd feel that considering that is answered and this is not, I'd close that as a duplicate of this and have this open as the 'canonical' question for matters of violence and dubious social value.